# breezejs : passing 64-bit filters in the ODATA url

Tags: javascript, breeze

I've got a 64-bit (long) property in my model. The metadata are correct and breezejs knows it is a 64-bit property.

Yet, when querying the data, the ODATA URL does not contain 'L' after the value and therefore I get an exception on the server as it thinks I'm trying to query against an int32.

So I've had to manually add the 'L' at the end of the filter.

Should this not be done automatically by breezejs ?

**EDIT**

In breezejs code, there's a fmtInt function. It goes there although the dataType is Int64. I guess there should be a fmtLong function, for adding a 'L'.

I've changed the following code :

```
  DataType.Int64 = DataType.addSymbol({
    defaultValue: 0, isNumeric: true, isInteger: true, quoteJsonOData: true,
    parse: coerceToInt,
    fmtOData:  fmtInt,
    getNext: getNextNumber
});
```

To

```
  DataType.Int64 = DataType.addSymbol({
    defaultValue: 0, isNumeric: true, isInteger: true, quoteJsonOData: true,
    parse: coerceToInt,
    fmtOData:  makeFloatFmt("L"),
    getNext: getNextNumber
});
```

And it works. Is that the correct way to do it ? If so, could there be a bug fix ?

Comment: I'll run some tests later today, but it does look like a bug... and if so, thanks for the fix :)

Comment: any news on this ? what was the tests result ?

Comment: I had the same issue, tanks for the fix Sam, just wondering when it will be fixed in the new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed as of Breeze 1.4.8 available now.

Answer (score 0):

Jay, this does not seem to be fixed with the new version. Is that right ?

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same issue with the 1.4.8 version. The following solved the problem by providing the Breeze DataType explicitly. This includes the "L" onto the OData property.

```
        var data = {
            value: number,
            dataType: breeze.DataType.Int64
        }

        query = query.where(new breeze.Predicate('column', '==', data));
```